# Laravel5.0: while passing variable in query function, it shows undefined variable

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am trying to pass a variable in my query. But error occurs: "undefined variable `$month`"

here is my controller part

```
public function due(Request $request){

    if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'POST') {

        $month = $request->month;
        if(isset($month)) {
            try {
                $val=DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
                if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName()) {
                    $month=$month;
                    $bRecord=DB::table('clients')->whereNotIn('ClientID', function($q){
                        $q->select('ClientID')->from('bills')
                            ->where(function ($query) use($month) {  //it shows $month is undefined, but why ??
                                $query->whereMonth('Date', '=', $month);
                            });
                    })->paginate(10);
                    return view('bills.dueRecord')->with('bRecord', $bRecord);
                }else{
                    $er="/connection status: database error";
                    return view('home')->with('error',$er);         //'error' is passed to home
                }

            } catch (\Exception $e){
                $er="/connection status: database error";
                return view('errors/503')->with('error',$er);
            }
        }

    }else{


    }
```

Comment: are u sure this $request->month returns a value ??

Comment: Having you a post var name 'month' ?

Comment: `$request->month()`  missing the ()

Comment: @john $request->month returns value, I've just check it.

Comment: @Grommy yes, I've post var from my view.

Comment: @Mihai month is not a method. It's a request object that I've post from my view.

Answer (score 0):

got my answer. I just need to pass the scope of $month two times in the query.

```
$bRecord=DB::table('clients')->whereNotIn('ClientID', function($q) use($month){
                        $q->select('ClientID')->from('bills')
                            ->where(function ($query) use($month) {
                                $query->whereMonth('Date', '=', $month);
                            });
                    })->paginate(10);
```